# How to hide/remove buttons in opportunity entity ms dynamic crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

![Ms dynamic Buttons on opportunity][1]

I am trying to remove buttons in opportunity .Can anyone  suggest how to remove/hide those buttons??

Comment: What exactly you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove or add buttons to the ribbon using a solution called: Ribbon Workbench
You can get the solution from here: https://www.develop1.net/public/Download%20Ribbon%20Workbench%202013.aspx

For more details how to use it:
https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench

Comment: I have to remove navigation bar of entity .